# How to implement jquery-ui plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery and want to add the jQuery UI plugin to my site. I have been referred to the [**jQueryUI site**](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and see the amount of plugins.
I allready downloaded (all) plugins, but the quantity of files confuses me... oO

Is there an easier way to implement it?
I'd be most appreciative!
Thanks :)

Comment: What's confusing with many files? Is it the order to add them in or how many you should add or something else?

Comment: `Implementing != Integrating`

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish, and what code have to written to that end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading it, you can access it from a public CDN.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

See [Google Hosted Libraries - Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Comment: you can also install it locally with npm by using 'npm install 'jquery-ui-dist'' and then refer to the according folder eg. <script type="application/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Nixen85 He asked for an alternative to downloading and installing locally.